# Exchanging messages between two C++ programs

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, message

I am new to creating Windows applications in C++. My task is to write two cpp files, one of which will send a number (x) to the other one, the other one will evaluate f(x) and send it back to the first one. I should implement it using Messages. Couldn't get anything specific online, Could someone pls give me a clue, where to start?
Great thanx!

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about window messages? If so, the sending app could use [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which would cause the receiving app to get its window procedure executed. Of course, this means that the receiving app needs to create a window whose window handle is somehow made available to the sending app.

Comment: [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx) is a candidate for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways.

- Using [WM_COPYDATA message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011(VS.85).aspx) to pass the data
- [Allocating global memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574(VS.85).aspx) to pass data and sending your own message, such that second program can read the data from memory
- [Sending a message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) (if two ints suit your needs to pass data)
- Using [named pipes](http://avid-insight.co.uk/joomla/component/k2/item/589-introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp)
- Using [TCP/IP local connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673(VS.85).aspx) (peer to peer or through a server)

Answer (score 0):

Look at ZeroMQ (http://zeromq.org ; cross-platform, LGPL). It is a very simple, lightweight and powerfull library. From the very basic level you can use it to exchange UDP-style datagrams, but through reliable transport (TCP or some variants). Also you have cancelling support, time-based polling and advanced network schemes (which are non-needed in your case). I've selected it for a similar task, and it performs very well.